# ansible: I want to use a group_var when I have a specific JOB_NAME in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Since JOB_NAME is available as a variable in Jenkins job.

I want a particular variable to be selected when there is certain string in the JOB_NAME variable

so based on different jenkins jobs I can register different variables.

I am trying something as below in group_vars, not sure if it would work.

```
command: echo "{{ lookup('env','JOB_NAME') }}"
      register: jenkins_job_name
when: installation in jenkins_job_name
  - topology: topology-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define a list of available topologies somewhere in your group vars and then select one with `set_fact` depending on `JOB_NAME` value.

For example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    topologies:
      prod: foo
      dev: bar
  tasks:
    - set_fact: topology="{{ topologies[lookup('env','JOB_NAME')] | default('unknown') }}"
    - debug: var=topology
```

This will set:

- `topology=foo` if `JOB_NAME=prod`
- `topology=bar` if `JOB_NAME=dev`
- `topology=unknown` otherwise

You may have a complex topology configuration object instead of simple `foo`/`bar` strings.